# Keytool importing from PEM/DER gives Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match

Tags: ssl, openssl, keytool

I'm doing a TCP server in java that communicates with a client in C.

My approach so far:

```
# Generate server's private and public keys
keytool -genkey -alias server -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 365 -keystore certs.jks -storepass le_pass
# Export for client
keytool -exportcert -alias server -keystore certs.jks -storepass le_pass -rfc -file server.pem
# Generate client's private and public keys
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -sha256 -out client.pem -keyout client.key
# Convert and import client's public key
openssl x509 -outform der -in client.pem -out client.der
keytool -import -alias server -keystore certs.jks -file client.der -storepass le_pass
```

The result (same if not converted):

`keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match`

If I use a different alias in the last line I get no error, but I don't think that's how it should be done?

Answer (score 0):

The first command `keytool -genkey -alias server ...` creates both private and public keys for the alias `server`.  No wonders it fails in the last command `keytool -import -alias server ...` -- you try to load a **different** public key for already existing name. The public key that doesn't match the existing private key for the alias `server`.

I don't think that you need to save client's public key under `server` alias. IMHO, it should be named `client`, shouldn't it?

```
keytool -import -alias CLIENT-keystore certs.jks -file client.der -storepass le_pass
```